# How safe is it to use Drush?

Tags: drupal, shell, command-line, drush

Since this is a beta-1 release, Is there anything which I should especially be worried about?

Answer (score 3):

I've used it for a long time and know several others that have done so without any problems. So I wouldn't be worried if I were you. But I haven't tested all the stuff like SQL queries and other db stuff you can do with drush. But it's really good for downloading modules, disabling/enabling modules, clearing cache and other stuff like that, that you tend to do a lot when developing.

Answer (score 2):

Drush is awesome. It does it's job well. The only thing to be wary of are things like:

- Have you modified any contrib modules
  yourself?
- "Stable" new releases may    contain
  bug(s) the maintainer did not
  catch.

But Drush does provide a backup of contrib modules to /backups.

Answer (score 1):

Drush is pretty safe when it comes to install/uninstall modules or themes (usually it also makes back-ups) but KEEP in mind when you update the core to back-up your entire web site. I have some web sites that I do maintenance and are not build by me that if I run:

```
drush up
```

I get weird behavior like: a theme gets deleted (that was the way it was built, I found out that moving the theme from root/themes/themename to root/sites/all/themes/custom/themename fix the problem), or the whole website just stops working (the build contains double code modules folder like: root/modules and root/modules/modules). So in general if your web site is build with best practices, drush is awesome, if not you might run into trouble.